# how to solve KeyError: "None of [Index(['MONTHS'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create train and test dataframes from a CSV file using pandas in Python.

I have double-checked that the column names in my CSV file match the column names in my code.

However, I am encountering an error message despite this verification.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data2010 = pd.read_csv("year2010.csv")

months = data2010[['MONTHS']]
print(months)

amount = data2010[['AMOUNT']]
print(amount)
```

This is the error message I am receiving:

```
KeyError: "['MONTHS'] not in index"
```

I have already confirmed the spelling and case sensitivity of the column names, and they match exactly with the csv file.

I also made sure that the file path is correct by checking the working directory.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or insights on what might be causing this error and how I can successfully create the train and test dataframes from my CSV file.

Comment: What does `print(data2010)` look like? That should be a dataframe and isolating one column like `data2010[['MONTHS']]` should work, so perhaps something is going wrong with reading the csv into python.

Comment: It looks like this                                                                                                                                                                                                        AMOUNT;MONTHS
0      1371138;1
1      1390441;2
2      2213733;3
3      1435277;4
4      2004501;5
5      2605059;6
6      1885869;7
7      1868608;8
8      2231714;9
9     1967509;10
10    1984011;11
11    2495116;12

Comment: You are only extracting one column. Hence, you will not be able to create a dataframe but a pandas series.

Comment: Add `sep=';'` to the `read_csv` call.